# How to rename columns in ORMLite?

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

How can we rename column name in ORMLite?

I am trying to write that query `SELECT id as _id from some_table`

Android Cursor Adapter requires us to have column named `_id` and `ORMLite` requires us to have column named `id`.

I am trying to write that query and return `Cursor` from this query.

```
Dao<NewsArticle, Long> newsArticleDao =
       ((SomeApp)mContext.getApplicationContext()).getDAOConnection().getDAO(
            NewsArticle.class);

QueryBuilder<NewsArticle, Long> query = newsArticleDao.queryBuilder().selectRaw(
      "`id` as `_id`");
PreparedQuery<NewsArticle> preparedQuery = query.prepare();

CloseableIterator<NewsArticle> iterator = newsArticleDao.iterator(preparedQuery);

AndroidDatabaseResults results =
        (AndroidDatabaseResults)iterator.getRawResults();
cursor = results.getRawCursor();
```

That's what I have so far but I am getting this error when I pass query to `iterator.`

`java.sql.SQLException: Could not compile this SELECT_RAW statement since the caller is expecting a SELECT statement.  Check your QueryBuilder methods.`

Comment: Your single quote around id looks odd. You've got an angled ` instead of a straight '. Might it just be a typo?

Comment: I put it while I am playing around, this is how ORMLite does and it is not problem you can ignore it. Otherwise it wouldn't give that error. My query is correct. I just don't know how to apply this query to `DAO` and get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I have to answer my question.

I still couldn't figure out how to rename column but I found the solution to problem.

Android `Custom Adapter` requires column named`_id` that's true but `ORMLite` doesn't require the column name to be `id`, I was wrong about that. It wants you to mark a column as id.

In my model, I marked my id and now it works like a charm.

```
 @DatabaseField(id = true)
 private long _id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can we rename column name in ORMLite?

Not sure I understand what you mean by rename.  I don't think you mean schema change here.  Are you talking about how to assign the name of the field in the database?  You can do:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "_id")
private long id;
```

> ORMLite requires us to have column named id.

Uh, no.  ORMLite shouldn't care what the name of your column is.  Maybe you are talking about Android?

> I am trying to write that query and return Cursor from this query.

Is this is a different question?

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not compile this SELECT_RAW statement since the caller is expecting a SELECT statement. Check your QueryBuilder methods.

You are getting this because you are calling:

```
newsArticleDao.queryBuilder().selectRaw(...);
```

And then calling:

```
query.prepare();
```

To quote from the [javadocs of `selectRaw(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#selectRaw%28java.lang.String...%29)

> ... This will turn the query into something only suitable for the Dao.queryRaw(String, String...) type of statement.

I think you want to assign the name of your column using `columnName`.  Have you looked at the [javadocs for `@DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html)?   Or maybe look up "column name" in the [online manual](http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.html)?

Comment: I was talking about "SELECT id as _id" when I pass `Cursor` to adapter. `CursorAdapter` requires `_id`. In my answer at bottom I explained that(I realized that after spending hours), as you said `ORMLite` doesn't require column name to be `id` but `ORMLite` wants us to mark a column as id (id=true). So I created a column named `_id` and marked id=true. So it satisfies `ORMLite` and `CursorAdapter`. Thanks for your explanation, I will check javadocs.